# Dynamic grid in ArcGIS layout view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules, arcgis-10.4, dynamic

I am trying to create a template for a standard output map layout including all surround elements. I am doing a temporary contract for a government department. I'll be done here in a few weeks, and they don't have an in-house GIS tech. I want to leave them with a template that requires no additional work to generate a map. Within ArcGIS (10.4) layout view, elements like legend and scale bar are dynamic with respect to layers and map scale, respectively. However, I don't know if it is possible to have a grid/graticule that dynamically adjusts the interval to be appropriate to the scale of the map. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with grid/graticules but you could create the grids as line features with dynamic labels (inside the map frame unfortunately) and set scale ranges to only show certain grids at certain scales.